# Problem in drawing square pattern in apex char

Tags: apexcharts

I am using react-apexcharts. I want to draw series (circle,star,square) on chart.

I am using pattern in apex chart but it does not show properly .

```
    fill: {
    type: 'pattern',
    pattern: {

      style: "squares",
      width: 6,
      height: 6,
      strokeWidth: 1,
      },

    }
```

[image: my attempt]

code on [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/frosty-cherry-6cifki?file=/src/components/ApexChartExample.tsx)

I want square series display that is shown in this

[image]